# python - urllib2 error 10060 on one specified website

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to download pdf file from website, but when I try to do a script I get error

> urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond

This happens only on one domain. If i google any example pdf and try download it, all works.

```
def download_file(download_url,username,password,name):
br = mechanize.Browser()
# Enable cookie support for urllib2 
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar) 

# Broser options 
br.set_handle_equiv( True ) 
br.set_handle_gzip( True ) 
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True ) 
br.set_handle_robots( False ) 
br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 2 ) 
br.addheaders = [('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36')]
br.set_proxies({"http": "*****",
                })
br.add_proxy_password(username, password)

r=br.open(download_url,timeout=180.0) #error here
```

EDIT:
I forgot to write - If I open my browser and paste link to pdf, it normally opens.

Comment: Can you connect to the same domain from your web browser? If not, the problem is that the site is down, or unreachable from your part of the internet, or something like that; there's nothing your code can do about that.

Comment: I can connect by web browser

Comment: Is it a public service that might have a reason to detect people trying to scrape their site in violation of their ToS, and therefore block you?